# Kubeflow Notebook integration with Gitlab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, gitlab, kubeflow, mlops

I am trying to integrate Kubeflow notebook with Gitlab (download the gitlab repo into notebook and run models by setting parameters). Currently we are doing it by importing the .tar.gz version of the gitlab repo as a first cell in the kubeflow notebook. The disadvantage here is we have to give the private token.

```
# %%bash
# wget -O kf.tar.gz https://gitlab.ikarem.io/projects/archive?sha=$$$$$$$$ --header='PRIVATE-TOKEN: $$$$$$$$'
# tar -zxvf kf.tar.gz
# mv kf-* kf
# rm -rf kf.tar.gz
```

Has anyone tried any other ways to integrate Kubeflow notebooks with Gitlab? Has Qubole helped here? I would really appreciate a detailed explanation on this. Thanks in advance for the time. :)

Comment: We use Kubeflow Notebooks combined with a private Gitlab instance. What we do is creating custom Docker images to run our notebooks with `git` installed. We also include Gitlab token per user in user's k8s/KF namespace as secret. The secret is then mounted into each user's notebook.

Comment: Hi Nichio, appreciate your response on this! I will add what worked for us.

Answer (score 0):

Something that worked for us which might help someone,

Individuals Add ssh keys to gitlab account. ssh key is secured with passphrase.(We use a team gitlab which is not a private instance.)

Then that ssh key is mounted while creating the docker image for notebook or it can also be added to home directory of notebook and added to notebooks by cloning it through notebook terminal.

export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i <ssh_key_path/ssh_key_name>'